# Creating a random number block of 0s and 1s

Tags: python, matrix

```
        import random

        a = [0]
        b = [1]

        for row in range(1):
            for colum in range(5):
                random.shuffle(a and b)
                print (" ".join( repr(e) for e in a + b[:5]))
```

Hey guys,

So I'm trying to create a 5 x 5 matrix filled with either 1s or 0s, however, having a bit of a hard time trying to achieve it. I gave it a go using the code above but no use. I'm new to python programming so be gentle haha.

This is the desired outcome: (There needs to be a MINIMUM of at least 10 1's within the matrix. Any idea of how to do that?

```
        0 1 1 1 1
        0 1 1 0 0
        0 1 1 0 1 
        1 1 0 1 1
        1 1 1 1 1
```

Any advice would be much, much appreciated. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 4):

You can start by getting a random number between 10 and 25, and create a list with that many 1's followed by enough 0's to get to 25.

```
import random
ones = random.randint(10, 25)
l = [1] * ones + [0] * (25-ones)
```

`[1] * ones` creates a list with `ones` 1's. `[0] * (25-ones)` creates a list with the remaining 0's. These are then concatenated using the `+` to produce a list with 25 total items.

Then shuffle this list:

```
random.shuffle(l)
```

and finally copy the values into the 5x5 matrix:

```
matrix = [l[i:i+5] for i in range(0, 25, 5)]
```

`range(0, 25, 5)` iterates from `0` to `25` by `5`, i.e. `0`, `5`, `10`, etc. Then `l[i:i+5]` takes a slice of 5 elements starting at each of those indexes. The list comprehension combines these all into a 2-dimensional list.

Comment: hey thanks for this, and I understand up until where you actually create the list. Would you be able to break this down for me?

l = [1] * ones + [0] * (25-ones)

also, how would i get it to format to be a 5 x 5, as at the min it's coming out on one line - again, thanks for the help!!

Comment: You mean `l = [1] * ones + [0] * (25-ones)`?

Comment: yes ^^' and also the [l[i:i+5] bit.. Sorry, I'm getting there!

Comment: I've added more explanation

Comment: Thanks for that, I understand it more now. However if I just do a print (matrix) it just comes out as [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]

How would I need to format that to get it to be 5 x 5?

Comment: I just tried it and got `[[1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1]]`. Are you sure you didn't do `print(l)`?

Comment: yeah we're getting the same thing, its just that its printing all as one line in stead of after 5 elements starting a new line. (Cant paste it here as it doesn't format properly)

Comment: That's just how `print()` prints lists. If you want it formatted differently, write a loop to print it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `numpy.random.randint`

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.randint(0, 2, (5, 5))
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

and then discard the solutions with less than 10 ones

For counting number of ones (as you only have 0s and 1s)

```
>>> data = np.random.randint(0, 2, (5, 5))
>>> data.sum()
13
```

Answer (score 0):

`random.choices` combined with a list comprehension is a quick way to do this. More often than not you will have 10 ones, but you can loop until you're certain:

```
from random import choices
total = 0
while total < 10:
    matrix = [choices((0, 1), k=5) for i in range(5)]
    total = sum(map(sum, matrix))

print(matrix)
```

> [[1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
>     [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
>     [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
>     [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
>     [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]]

Answer (score 0):

In fact, my dear friend there is a simple approach for this problem, and you should put all your code after "if **name** == "**main**":".

```
import random


def log_matrix(matrix):
    for r in range(len(matrix)):
        print(" ".join([str(i) for i in matrix[r]]))


def sum_matrix(matrix):
    return sum(map(sum, matrix))


def gen_matrix(row, col, minimum):
    random_matrix = [[random.choice([0, 1]) for _ in range(row)]
                     for _ in range(col)]
    while sum_matrix(random_matrix) < minimum:
        random_matrix[random.choice([0, row - 1])][random.choice(
            [0, col - 1])] = 1
    return random_matrix


if __name__ == "__main__":
    random_matrix = gen_matrix(5, 5, 10)
    log_matrix(random_matrix)
```

Comment: How does this ensure at least 10 1's?

Comment: @Barmar Because you use the choice function in the random library.  This function will return the value in parameters randomly. (in this case [0,1])

Comment: @Barmar You can checkout this document, my dear friend .https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html#random.choice

Comment: That just returns a choice betwen 0 and 1, it doesn't ensure that the final matrix has at least 10 1's in it.

Comment: Did you miss this part of the question: **There needs to be a MINIMUM of at least 10 1's within the matrix.**

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, I do miss that.  I updated the answer, this ensures at least 10 1's.

Comment: I think you're doing MAXIMUM of 10, not minimum.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry for that, I updated the answer, now it is minimum.